# Accessing/Updating Nested Dictionary through Segues

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested

I'm having a problem. I'm making an app using swift where you choose a continent through buttons on the main view controller. This takes you to a second view controller where the countries of that continent and its populations show up on a text view. Later you add a country and population from a third view controller using text fields, then add this information back to the previews text view. Adding this to its respective continents.

I have a nested dictionary in the first view controller. How do I add information from the third view and show on the second view when the data model is on the first view?

This is my data model:

```
var Dictionary : [String: [String: Int]] = [

"North America" : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
"Asia"          : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
"South America" : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
"Africa"        : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
"Europe"        : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
"Oceania"       : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0]

]
```

I'm new to swift that's why of my complete confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This example is in Swift 3

From what I understand, you need to pass and mutate a dataset between your views.

I'll provide a simple way for you to pass your dictionary between views, you'll be able to pass your data-set along, edit it, and your changes to your data set will traverse between your views.

Define a protocol that tells your view controllers that they must have a dictionary of type `[String: [String: Int]]` variable.

```
protocol ViewPassesData : class {
    var dictionary : [String: [String: Int]] { get set }
}
```

Make each of your view controllers that will be handling your data conform to this protocol.

```
class FirstViewController : UIViewController, ViewPassesData { //...}

class SecondViewController : UIViewController, ViewPassesData { //...}

class ThirdViewController : UIViewController, ViewPassesData { //...}
```

You'll need to add this to your first view controller:

```
var dictionary : [String: [String: Int]] = [

        "North America" : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
        "Asia"          : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
        "South America" : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
        "Africa"        : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
        "Europe"        : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0],
        "Oceania"       : ["country1" : 0, "country2" : 0, "country3" : 0]

    ]
```

and this to view controllers 2 & 3

```
var dictionary : [String: [String: Int]] = [:]
```

Now that you've defined a common interface between your view controllers and you've told your view controllers they *must* adhere to this commonality, you can simply paste this prepare for segue function into each of your view controllers. Note that we're casting our view controllers as our protocol type. Since each of our view controllers adhere to our protocol, the cast should go over perfectly fine and we should be able to access the dictionary that lives in the controller we're casting to.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {      
    guard let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewPassesData
       else { fatalError("wrong vc type") }

    vc.dictionary = self.dictionary
}
```

To test what I've just shown you, add a print statement to your viewDidLoad in each view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("dictionary: \(dictionary)")
}
```

You'll see that your data set is being transferred between your views. You'll be able to update your data set and pass it to the next view.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed.